# How to filter _source before it is returned back from API?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have many field in `_source` of indexed document. However I don't need all of them to be returned form search query. For now for each found document the whole `_source` is returned. How I can force to receive only specific fields of each `_source`?

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So to answer your answer in general,

For version < 1

use (in search request)

```
{
   "fields" : ["fields you want to get"]
}
```

so response contains fields, not source

if version > = 1 then,

you can use

```
{
   "_source":[ "fields to include"]
}
```

source filtering can be found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. I tried "fields" before but it "flattened" source. Didnt know about _source options. It works for me!

Comment: Here's an article that covers the different approaches: https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-fields/